# If statement in Python QGIS Raster Calculator

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, raster-calculator, if-else, if-statement

I would like to perform a raster calculation with the if condition and I wrote this code:

```
import qgis
import gdal 
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer

inputpath='/Users/macbook/Desktop/TESI/PROGETTO/rasterUfinali/U_1990.tif'
inputpath2='/Users/macbook/Desktop/TESI/PROGETTO/SIGMAmax/SIGMAmax,har.tif'
inputpath3 = '/Users/macbook/Desktop/TESI/PROGETTO/sigm/sigmahar90.tif'
inputpath4 = '/Users/macbook/Desktop/TESI/PROGETTO/lambdamin/lambminhar90.tif'
outputpath = '/Users/macbook/Desktop/TESI/PROGETTO/alfamax/alphamaxhar90.tif'


inputrasterfile = QgsRasterLayer(inputpath)

entries = []
ras = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
ras.ref = 'ras@1'
ras.raster = inputrasterfile
ras.bandNumber = 1
entries.append( ras )

inputrasterfile2 = QgsRasterLayer(inputpath2)

ras2 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
ras2.ref = 'ras@2'
ras2.raster = inputrasterfile2
ras2.bandNumber = 1
entries.append( ras2 )


inputrasterfile3 = QgsRasterLayer(inputpath3)

ras3 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
ras3.ref = 'ras@3'
ras3.raster = inputrasterfile3
ras3.bandNumber = 1
entries.append( ras3 )


inputrasterfile4 = QgsRasterLayer(inputpath4)

ras4 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
ras4.ref = 'ras@4'
ras4.raster = inputrasterfile4
ras4.bandNumber = 1
entries.append( ras4 )

if '(ras@2 - ras@1) > 0':
    alpha_max='1'
else: alpha_max = 'ras@3 / (1-2.71828^(ras@4))'

new_path = outputpath
print(alpha_max)

alfamax= QgsRasterCalculator(alpha_max, new_path, 'GTiff', inputrasterfile.extent(), inputrasterfile.width(), inputrasterfile.height(), entries )
alfamax.processCalculation()
iface.addRasterLayer(new_path)
```

The code works and print a valid output raster, but it doesn't respect the "if condition", because it prints out `alpha_max = 1` even where `(ras@1 - ras@1)<0`.

Can someone tell me where is the mistake?

Comment: You erased a previous comment in my answer but, it is the same recommendation.  I tried my code out and it works without any issues (because I fixed your wrong references to your raster layers). So, **copy/paste** my code, erase my paths and uncomment yours. It should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mistake I see is that you are not passing your variables into the if statement. You are actually passing a string. Let me explain. Open your python interpreter and past in the following code and run it. You will see that without even defining **ras@2** or **ras@1** you will always result in alpha_max = 1. This is because you passed your variables in quotation marks.

```
if '(ras@2 - ras@1) > 0':
    alpha_max='1'
else: alpha_max = 'ras@3 / (1-2.71828^(ras@4))'

print(alpha_max)
```

You are essentially saying: **if "**string**" > 0**, which translates to "***if my 'string' is not empty***". You are essentially comparing your string to the Boolean True/False. If you're string is not empty, it will always have a value of 1, or True. If you pass an empty string, you would have a value of 0, or False. You need to pass your variables to the if statement not inside a string. Also, it is not clear what aspect of these rasters you are trying to compare. Overall size, height, width, resolution, etc. You will likely need to try something like this, but also substituting in what value you are actually trying to compare for the values of ras1,ras2,ras3,and ras4:

```
if (ras2 - ras1) > 0:
    alpha_max='1'
else: alpha_max = ras3 / (1-2.71828^(ras4))

print(alpha_max)
```

Comment: What I want to compare is the value of each pixel of ras@2 and ras@1. If I try to write the statement you suggested me it gives me error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'QgsRasterCalculatorEntry' and 'int'"

Comment: If you are trying to compare the value of each pixel individually, you may want to try and deal with this as a numpy array and you will need to nest this inside a loop. Currently the code/psuedo code just says: "If (raster2 - raster 1) > 0" which just means. There are also numerous types of cell statistics already available and it may be easier to just call one of them as they are designed to work on a per-cell basis. https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#cell-statistics

Comment: Sorry I haven't understood. Each pixel of the raster 2 and raster 1 that I have as input as a value; by comparing the difference pixel by pixel, I want to get an output raster that respect the statement. But I can't find how to do it in the link... sorry I am a beginner with this stuff

Comment: Check out section 3, "Example computation: NDVI". While NDVI is for vegetation difference, the concept is the same: The difference between raster bands. Maybe it will point you in the right direction. https://geohackweek.github.io/raster/04-workingwithrasters/

Comment: also maybe this will help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndhMzlZPSrY

Comment: QGIS Raster calculator doesn't use If...else statements. It uses another logic instead because is PyQGIS 3 (not pure Python 3). Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

QGIS Raster calculator doesn't use If...else statements. It uses [this logic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385763/raster-calculator-if-statement/385899#385899) instead. So, functional version of your code (with my paths) looks as follows.

```
import qgis
import gdal 
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer

#inputpath='/Users/macbook/Desktop/TESI/PROGETTO/rasterUfinali/U_1990.tif'
inputpath='/home/zeito/Desktop/PROGETTO/rasterUfinali/U_1990.tif'

#inputpath2='/Users/macbook/Desktop/TESI/PROGETTO/SIGMAmax/SIGMAmax,har.tif'
inputpath2='/home/zeito/Desktop/PROGETTO/SIGMAmax/SIGMAmax,har.tif'

#inputpath3 = '/Users/macbook/Desktop/TESI/PROGETTO/sigm/sigmahar90.tif'
inputpath3 = '/home/zeito/Desktop/PROGETTO/sigm/sigmahar90.tif'

#inputpath4 = '/Users/macbook/Desktop/TESI/PROGETTO/lambdamin/lambminhar90.tif'
inputpath4 = '/home/zeito/Desktop/PROGETTO/lambdamin/lambminhar90.tif'

#outputpath = '/Users/macbook/Desktop/TESI/PROGETTO/alfamax/alphamaxhar90.tif'
outputpath = '/home/zeito/Desktop/PROGETTO/alfamax/alphamaxhar90.tif'

inputrasterfile = QgsRasterLayer(inputpath)

entries = []
ras1 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
ras1.ref = 'ras1@1'
ras1.raster = inputrasterfile
ras1.bandNumber = 1
entries.append( ras1 )

inputrasterfile2 = QgsRasterLayer(inputpath2)

ras2 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
ras2.ref = 'ras2@1'
ras2.raster = inputrasterfile2
ras2.bandNumber = 1
entries.append( ras2 )

inputrasterfile3 = QgsRasterLayer(inputpath3)

ras3 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
ras3.ref = 'ras3@1'
ras3.raster = inputrasterfile3
ras3.bandNumber = 1
entries.append( ras3 )

inputrasterfile4 = QgsRasterLayer(inputpath4)

ras4 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
ras4.ref = 'ras4@1'
ras4.raster = inputrasterfile4
ras4.bandNumber = 1
entries.append( ras4 )

alpha_max = '(' + ras2.ref + ' - ' + ras1.ref + ' > 0 ' + ')*1 ' + ' + (' + ras2.ref + ' - ' + ras1.ref + ' <= 0 ' + ')* ' + ras3.ref + ' / ( 1 - 2.71828^' + ras4.ref + ')'
print(alpha_max)

new_path = outputpath

alfamax= QgsRasterCalculator(alpha_max, 
                             new_path, 
                             'GTiff', 
                             inputrasterfile.extent(), 
                             inputrasterfile.width(), 
                             inputrasterfile.height(), 
                             entries )

alfamax.processCalculation()
iface.addRasterLayer(new_path)
```

After run above code in Python Console, I got following result. Observe how is printed **alpha_max** (it contains used conditions of your formula).

[image]