# Set raster values to a specific number

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I have a raster dataset with pixel values ranging between 1 and 255. I would like to set 5-255 to 5 and leave pixels with 1,2,3,4 value in QGIS.

I know I can use the raster calculator `(raster >=5)* 5`, however, it classifies 5-255 values to 5 but also sets 1,2,3,4 value to 0. What should I do to avoid changing the values between 1 and 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One tool you can use in QGIS is [Reclassify by Table](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#reclassify-by-table).
Your table should look like this:
[image: Reclassification table where values from 1 to 1 become 1, values from 2 to 2 become 2, values from 3 to 3 become 3, values from 4 to 4 become 4, and values from 5 to 255 become 5.]

Comment: Thanks @ChloeG for reminding this tool.

Answer (score 8):

Use [Raster Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html#raster-calculator) with an if-condition, available [since QGIS 3.22](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/414826/88814), with this expression:

```
if ("raster@1" >= 5 , 5, "raster@1")
```