# Two different "Raster Calculator" tools in QGIS give different results

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I am working on QGIS 3.26.3-Buenos Aires on Windows 10 and just realised that it has two different raster calculators. I believe they are both from the standard version, no plug-in. They have different UI and give different results. Why is it the case ?

The first raster calculator (1) is accessible via the **Menu > Raster > Raster Calculator**:

[image]

I found the other one (2) via the toolbox, **Raster Analysis > Raster Calculator**:

[image]

I used both calculator to perform a simple addition on the same layer, but the results are different! See image below. *"downstream_topotoR_5m_wgs84@1"+42.727* is from the menu calculator (1) and *Output* is from the toolbox calculator (2).

[image]

I noticed that the original raster file I am working with is Float32 type with -3.40282e+38 as No-Data. So is *Output*, but *"downstream_topotoR_5m_wgs84@1"+42.727* is Float64 and has n-a as No_Data. This is probably where the difference is but I do not understand how this affects the data.
Also, I didn't see any options for that in any of the raster calculators.

Comment: So only no data cells are affected? The cells containing data result in the same output? In fact, there must also be a 3rd Raster calculator: QGIS native, GDAL and SAGA: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/414826/88814

Comment: And even a 4th: GRASS  Mapcalc: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/grass/grass_tools.html#moderate-fa-the-mapcalc-tool

Comment: With a look at your screenshots: both show the QGIS native Raster calculator, seem just to be different versions. The Toolbox is just the place where you find **all** algorithms and tools you can access on QGIS in the same place. Some also appear in the menus, others not

Comment: Thank you for these comments. Indeed it looks like two different versions. The one that can be found in the menu seems to be the latest one (with the IF statement) but also the one that messes up no-data cells and change the original format. I will get the latest QGIS version and check again.

Comment: So maybe just Float32 has other NoData values as Float64 and the rest is the same? You should check this in report back.

Comment: It is the same in the QGIS 3.30.2 and to me it is a bug. The raster menu's calculator uses Foat64 and doesn't recognise -3.40282e+38 as no-data value. See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/47812.